# django runserver error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, django, linux, ubuntu

So yesterday I did a fresh install of Ubuntu11.10 but keeping my home directory with my virtualenvs, I installed virtual env and was able to logon my previous virtual env, but now when I try to run python manage.py runserver under the virtualenv I get the following error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Any idea how to fix this? I tried installing ssl package of python, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: You might need to install the general SSL package for your OS. Check your software repo/package manager for what's available.

Comment: I know the problem now, its because my virtualenv was still using the ubuntu 11.04 general ssl package. I am currently trying to create a new virtualenv and see if that works. Thanks for your suggestion though. The general ssl package is already installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same error installing OpenStack on Ubuntu 11.10.

Running locate showed I only had version 1.0.0 and not 0.9.8

$ locate libssl.so 
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0

I fixed it using: 
$sudo apt-get install libssl0.9.8

Comment: yea good to provide it in here, maybe somebody who googles for the error like i usually do has the same proble as you do :)

Comment: lol seems you also added a comment on my blog haha, and i answered it with your answer on stackoverflow hahah what a coincidence
http://blog.samos-it.com/ubuntu-11-10-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libssl-so-0-9-8-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory/

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by creating a new virtualenv and installing all packages again. It seems my old virtualenv was still linking to the ubuntu 11.04 general ssl package, but the location was updated.